# Angular: How to let user go directly to lazy loaded URL?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have an Angular-4 app with several modules, some of which are lazy-loaded, and it all works fine when the user starts at the "home" page.

Before I added lazy-loading, the user could **also** cold/directly load any legal app URL (say, `localhost:4200/foo`), and that worked fine too *(aka deep-linking)*.

But, after changing the module associated with `/foo` to lazy-loading, you now get a blank page, no errors, and displaying a URL of `localhost:4200` when you cold load `localhost:4200/foo`. *(Again, lazy-loaded `/foo` works fine if the user navigates to it via the router.)*

So, is there a trick to allow the user to directly launch a URL that is handled by a lazy-loaded module? Or, do you give up that ability if you use lazy-loading?

Comment: can you share the relevant code?

Comment: no, as usual it is a big code base hence the simplified question. I am hoping someone posts a link to an official page saying "you can't do that", or a link to an existence proof (i.e. an example showing that you _can_ do it)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I bit the bullet and implemented a toy example, based on this tutorial:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

and, it was possible to directly load `localhost:4200/lazy`.

So, it is not forbidden per se, and there must be something nastily complicated in my real code that is the culprit.